# How can I do a step-by-step tracing on amd-v(svm)?

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

### Introduction:

I can't figure out how I can do a trace on an amd hypervisor. Is there something like eflags.tf in svm? so that I can trace the instructions

### Main problem:

I initially thought that amd has something like intel, where I vmwrite in CPU_BASED_VM_EXEC_CONTROL(0x00004002) value CPU_BASED_MONITOR_TRAP_FLAG(0x08000000), but amd-v does not have this, and the tf flag does not work. I also found information that the rf flag can also affect this somehow, but I didn't understand how, since when I switch the rf flag to 1, nothing is intercepted in SvmExitHandler either.

### Main question:

Thus the main question:
Can someone tell me how can I trace instructions in the case of amd-v? i.e., for example, initially I virtualize the entire system, after that, for example, I compiled a large application through the clang compiler with my optimization phases, then I need to trace it like:

1. vmrun
2. instruction from a guest
3. vmexit
4. my SvmExitHandler function with Exitcode dispatcher
5. some actions in Exitcode dispatcher
6. back to the first stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you need to intercept DB exception, and then process it in SvmExitHandler. Only I haven't figured out how to get out of it yet, because after turning on the tf flag, I'm staying there forever.

How can you do that:

https://github.com/HoShiMin/Kernel-Bridge

You need to Enable this interception

Private->Guest.ControlArea.InterceptExceptions.Bitmap.InterceptionVectorDB = TRUE;

and you can catch DB exception:

```
extern "C" VMM_STATUS SvmVmexitHandler(PRIVATE_VM_DATA* Private, GUEST_CONTEXT* Context, GUEST_SSE_CONTEXT* SSeContext, GUEST_AVX_CONTEXT* AvxContext)
    {
        // Load the host state:
        __svm_vmload(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(Private->VmmStack.Layout.InitialStack.HostVmcbPa));
        
        // Restore the guest's RAX that was overwritten by host's RAX on #VMEXIT:
        Context->Rax = Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rax;

        VMM_STATUS Status = VMM_STATUS::VMM_CONTINUE;

        switch (Private->Guest.ControlArea.ExitCode)
        {
        case VMEXIT_CPUID:
        {
            CPUID_REGS Regs = {};
            int Function = static_cast<int>(Context->Rax);
            int SubLeaf = static_cast<int>(Context->Rcx);
            __cpuidex(Regs.Raw, Function, SubLeaf);

            switch (Function) {
            case CPUID_VMM_SHUTDOWN:
            {
                // Shutdown was triggered:
                Status = VMM_STATUS::VMM_SHUTDOWN;
                break;
            }
            case CPUID::Generic::CPUID_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION_NUMBER_AND_VENDOR_ID:
            {
                Context->Rax = Regs.Regs.Eax;
                GetHvCpuName(Context->Rbx, Context->Rcx, Context->Rdx);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                Context->Rax = Regs.Regs.Eax;
                Context->Rbx = Regs.Regs.Ebx;
                Context->Rcx = Regs.Regs.Ecx;
                Context->Rdx = Regs.Regs.Edx;
                break;
            }
            }
            break;
        }
        case VMEXIT_MSR:
        {
            if ((Context->Rcx & MAXUINT32) == static_cast<unsigned int>(AMD_MSR::MSR_EFER) && Private->Guest.ControlArea.ExitInfo1)
            {
                EFER Efer = {};
                Efer.Value = ((Context->Rdx & MAXUINT32) << 32) | (Context->Rax & MAXUINT32);
                if (!Efer.Bitmap.SecureVirtualMachineEnable)
                {
                    InjectEvent(&Private->Guest, INTERRUPT_VECTOR::GeneralProtection, EXCEPTION_VECTOR::FaultTrapException, 0); // #GP (Vector = 13, Type = Exception)
                    break;
                }
                Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Efer = Efer.Value;
            }
            break;
        }
        case VMEXIT_VMRUN:
        {
            InjectEvent(&Private->Guest, INTERRUPT_VECTOR::GeneralProtection, EXCEPTION_VECTOR::FaultTrapException, 0); // #GP (Vector = 13, Type = Exception)
            break;
        }
        case VMEXIT_EXCP_DB://Trace, you can call this by TF flag switch to 1
        {
                    KdPrint(("RIP %p\n", Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rip));

            Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rax = Context->Rax;
            return Status;
        }
        }

        if (Status == VMM_STATUS::VMM_SHUTDOWN)
        {
            // We should to devirtualize this processor:
            Context->Rax = reinterpret_cast<UINT64>(Private) & MAXUINT32; // Low part
            Context->Rbx = Private->Guest.ControlArea.NextRip;
            Context->Rcx = Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rsp;
            Context->Rdx = reinterpret_cast<UINT64>(Private) >> 32; // High part

            // Load the guest's state:
            __svm_vmload(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(Private->VmmStack.Layout.InitialStack.GuestVmcbPa));
            
            // Store the GIF - Global Interrupt Flag:
            _disable();
            __svm_stgi();

            // Disable the SVM by resetting the EFER.SVME bit:
            EFER Efer = {};
            Efer.Value = __readmsr(static_cast<unsigned long>(AMD_MSR::MSR_EFER));
            Efer.Bitmap.SecureVirtualMachineEnable = FALSE;
            __writemsr(static_cast<unsigned long>(AMD_MSR::MSR_EFER), Efer.Value);

            // Restoring the EFlags:
            __writeeflags(Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rflags);
        }

        Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rax = Context->Rax;
        
        // Go to the next instruction:
        Private->Guest.StateSaveArea.Rip = Private->Guest.ControlArea.NextRip;

        return Status;
    }
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer... you should edit this into your question or add as a comment.